Python Error: Prog Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:2241: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
I have defined a method to calculate upper lower limits for transaction counts in my data for each day of the week using t distribution after removal of outliers using IQR. However, when I call for the method, I get the error in the subject line. Not able to decipher the issue, and the output isn't as expected which means there is some issue with the 'multiplication' as indicated by the error. Where am I going wrong?
Code is below.
def trans_threshold(Day):
    Tran_Cnt=Tran_Cnt_DF[['Sample',Day]].dropna()
    Tran_Cnt=Tran_Cnt.astype({'Sample':'str'})
    Tran_Cnt.dtypes
    #Finding outliers in Transaction counts via IQR
    X_Tran = Tran_Cnt.drop('Sample', axis=1)
    Tran_arr1 = X_Tran.values
    #Finding the first quartile
    Tran_q1= np.quantile(Tran_arr1, 0.25)
    # finding the 3rd quartile
    Tran_q3 = np.quantile(Tran_arr1, 0.75)
    # finding the iqr region
    Tran_iqr = Tran_q3-Tran_q1
    # finding upper and lower outliers
    Tran_upper_bound = Tran_q3+(1.5*Tran_iqr)
    Tran_lower_bound = Tran_q1-(1.5*Tran_iqr)
    # removing outliers
    Tran_arr2 = Tran_arr1[(Tran_arr1 >= Tran_lower_bound) & (Tran_arr1 <= Tran_upper_bound)]
    #Using t distribution for Transaction count Limits
    Tran_Threshold_mat=st.t.interval(confidence=0.99999999999, df=len(Tran_arr2-1),
             loc=np.mean(Tran_arr2),
             scale=st.sem(Tran_arr2))
    return Tran_Threshold_mat

Tran_Cnt_DF=Tran_Cnt_DF_FullFeed

Day='Mon'
#Transaction Limit for Full Feed
trn_lim_ETY781_Mon = trans_threshold(Day)
trn_lim_lst_ETY781_Mon = list(trn_lim_ETY781_Mon)
trn_upper_lim_ETY781_Mon=trn_lim_lst_ETY781_Mon.pop(1)
trn_lower_lim_ETY781_Mon=trn_lim_lst_ETY781_Mon.pop()

I got the below error. What does this mean?
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:2241: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply   lower_bound = _a * scale + loc C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:2242: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply   upper_bound = _b * scale + loc

I can understand it is referring to the below lines, but the formula is correct! However, my data has blank and null values in places, could it be because of that?
    Tran_upper_bound = Tran_q3+(1.5*Tran_iqr)
    Tran_lower_bound = Tran_q1-(1.5*Tran_iqr)

The dataframe Tran_Cnt_DF is below
Sample  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
0   1   2180    2911    2361    9101    3080    5   0
1   2   3188    2957    2899    8515    2824    5   0
2   3   21  1855    3850    8961    3279    5   0
3   4   0   2011    4294    2920    3228    5   0
4   5   2106    2419    2496    2486    2845    5   0
5   6   1331    2496    2561    5675    2965    5   0
6   7   2454    2169    2282    15499   3508    5   0
7   8   2762    2607    2706    10028   3482    5   2
8   9   2209    2214    2514    7760    3201    5   0
9   10  207 1772    2885    8152    3175    5   0
10  11  1281    2602    2369    6012    3635    5   0
11  12  2093    2691    3035    9326    3319    5   0
12  13  3010    3524    2456    8005    2355    5   0
13  14  2300    2268    3041    9424    3026    5   0
14  15  2103    2668    2801    6715    3808    5   0
15  16  3167    3629    5839    10360   3405    5   4
16  17  2345    2790    3328    12613   142 0   0
17  18  2924    3154    730 4108    4128    5   0
18  19  3691    2335    2386    4369    2256    5   0
19  20  2261    2800    2577    8529    6182    5   0
20  21  2581    3600    129 11525   5648    5   0
21  22  2460    2962    2666    7238    2270    5   0
22  23  2115    3103    1763    8307    3261    5   0
23  24  3671    4059    733 6075    3244    0   0
24  25  1456    4349    3346    8344    3960    5   18
25  26  2121    2437    2667    8810    3174    5   0
26  27  1515    2673    2467    11379   4615    5   0
27  28  805 3211    1837    7533    5664    5   0
28  29  2451    2906    9249    8247    3784    5   0
29  30  1636    4521    7412    10167   5460    5   0
30  31  2443    5164    3165    4056    4849    5   0
31  32  3219    5145    5538    6166    2453    5   0
32  33  5180    2182    9175    6509    5223    10  0
33  34  2429    5591    2822    5514    3846    5   2
34  35  2145    5153    5262    5322    3850    5   0
35  36  4714    4176    4187    5045    800 5   0
36  37  3164    4766    6407    5759    3910    5   0

